# Javascript split addes extra arrays: remove and __proto__

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am doing a simple string split on a VF page, when I do it directly from the console log, it returns what I expected. However, when I do it from the VF page it adds extra arrays in the result that is breaking the rest of the JS after I do some operations with the returned array.

The below image shows what the split returns
[image: Split result]

However, when I click in the object it has:
[image: Extra Parameters after split]

why VF pages add this? how can I clean up the array to delete this extra 2 objects.

My function or JS looks like this:

```
var infoValue = 'Loan Date~Loan Number~Loan Amount|15/03/2016~1042~620|15/03/2016~1044~372';
var x = parseInfoValue(infoValue);
console.log(x);

function parseInfoValue(s) { 
    var b = s.split('|');
    var header = b.shift().split('~');
    return b.reduce(function(acc, data) {
        var c = data.split('~');
        var obj = {};
        c.forEach(function(value, i){
            console.log(header[i]);
            obj[header[i]] = value;
        })
        acc.push(obj);
        return acc;
    },[]);
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Visualforce is the culprit here? I'm not sure what `remove` is, but `__proto__` is the accessor for a Javascript Object's `Prototype` property, and __every__ object has it. Do you have additional code that uses the output of `parseInfoValue()`? If so, you may want to look into using the `hasOwnProperty()` (Javascript) method in some for loop to filter out inherited properties.

Comment: could you please tell which part of code is breaking because of __proto__ . Actually it should break your code.

Comment: i think, instead of c.forEach, next should be used: for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){...} (as well as C is array)